# tweepy error.. Method doesn't exist

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I need to run the twitter api call for friendship lookup. The details of the call are here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friendships/lookup

I am using tweepy to do this in python, however, it's not present in tweepy at all. I did a little digging and found out that this method has been added to tweepy and I have the latest version. Check this:

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/aa055fe16c73f80a0a36279bfc83e40af3d93008

Whenever I try to run api.lookup_friendship. It doesn't exist in the code. Any way I can get this to work?

Comment: Can you confirm that `python -c 'import tweepy; print tweepy.__version__'` gives you `1.11`?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters On an additional note, I am on mac osx mountain lion. Where is the source file for tweepy located? I can just add the code from git can't I?

Comment: Locate it with bin/python -c 'import tweepy; print tweepy.__file__'; I can confirm 1.11 is missing the method, strange.

Comment: Can you post the sample code that doesn't work?

Comment: @AndreBossard: `import tweepy; api = tweepy.API(); api.lookup_friendships()` -> `AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'lookup_friendships'`. There is no such function defined in the `api.py` file included in the 1.11 distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The commit you link to wasn't merged with the tweepy master branch until [August 19th](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/ab2be4621b9146fca0eef173516d02104365a5ef), which was after the [1.11 release was cut (on August 14th 2012)](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/80e5edd61b207e4f15de11a79474972489c56247). Until 1.12 comes out you'll need to install directly from git to get this feature.<sup>*</sup>

To install the current development version, using pip, use:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git#egg=tweepy
```

Once you've run that command, the `.lookup_friendships()` method is available:

```
>>> import tweepy
>>> api = tweepy.API()
>>> api.lookup_friendships
<bound method API.lookup_friendships of <tweepy.api.API object at 0x10a7ad290>>
>>> api.lookup_friendships()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/tweepy/src/tweepy/tweepy/api.py", line 285, in lookup_friendships
    return self._lookup_friendships(list_to_csv(user_ids), list_to_csv(screen_names))
  File "/private/tmp/tweepy/src/tweepy/tweepy/binder.py", line 184, in _call
    method = APIMethod(api, args, kargs)
  File "/private/tmp/tweepy/src/tweepy/tweepy/binder.py", line 34, in __init__
    raise TweepError('Authentication required!')
tweepy.error.TweepError: Authentication required!
```

I didn't bother to log in; the above demonstration does show it works, though. :-)

---

<sup>*</sup> Version 1.12, including this change, was released Nov. 8th 2012.